# How do I get the "Navigate to..." voice command on my droid x?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, voice-command, navigation

I have a droid x and have used both navigation and the voice commands.   Reading online, I see lots of people make reference to using voice commands to say "Navigate to 123 Main Street" or similar.

My droid x does not have "Navigate to..." as an option for voice commands.

What do I need to do to enable "Navigate to..." as an option for voice commands?

Comment: Which version of Android?

Comment: @aleverett Android. 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [Google Navigation](http://www.google.com/mobile/navigation/)?

> ### Search by voice
>
> Speak your destination instead of typing (English only): "Navigate to the de Young Museum in San Francisco".

Comment: I am using Google navigation on my fairly stock droid x. I have voice commands to make calls, play music, but not navigation.

Comment: OK.  Do you have the latest [Voice Search](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch)?